# curly braces php on class

Tags: php, class, curly-braces

I have a simple class... I need to update **public $token** if it is setted. My code is:

```
<?php
class Amazon {
    public $token = '';
    public function update($key = '', $value = '')
    {
        if(isset($this->"{$key}"))
        {
            $this->"{$key}" = $value;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'**

Comment: `$this->{$key}`, not `$this->"{$key}"`.... and why not take a look at the magic `__set()` method? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the quotes. `$this->{$key}`